# How to set enum value to dropdown using Knockoutjs or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, knockout.js, enums

I am having dropdwon and values are populated by model with enum.
Here is my code:

```
 public enum Types
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        New=1,
        Cancelled=2
   }
```

My Models:

```
    public class TypeMappings
    {
        public Types Type { get; set; }
        public string TypeString { get; set; }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public List<TypeMappings> Types { get; set; }
        public Types SelectedType { get; set; }
     }
```

My cshtml code:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedType , new SelectList(Model.Types , "Type ", "TypeString"), new { id = "ddType",  data_bind = "value:type,valueUpdate: 'input', css:{ faultyBrush: (typeValid()==false)},attr: { title: typeError }" })
```

MY JqueryCode:

```
 this.type = ko.observable($('#ddType').val());
function reset(){
         this.type(0);
         $('#ddType').val(0);
}
```

On cancel button click,I am calling `reset()` function which should reset the dropdown to enum value 0(Unknown).

How can we do this using either JQuery or knockoutJS.

Comment: You've already bound `ddType` to your model's `type` observable, so no need to manually reset the `val()` using jQuery.

Comment: but when i tried to set 0(Unknown) value, its not setting(text in dropdown is not changing to unknown). How can i achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `options` ko binding? I don't think the SelectList automatically binds the options observable, so when you change the select option, the value binding can't get data from anywhere.

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI let us know if you need further assistance

Comment: Thanks for the support.Sorry for delayed response. I create as constants and set the value and it got fixed.